# How to write a join query for SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables `source_product` and `target_product` as shown here:

**source_product**:

```
pitem_id    prev_id citem_id    crev_id qty     check_no    status
-------------------------------------------------------------------
AAA         null    null        null    null    null        null
AAA         A       Item_2      B       2       100         No
AAA         A       Item_3      A       1       100         No
```

**target_product**:

```
pitem_id    prev_id citem_id    crev_id qty     check_no    status
-------------------------------------------------------------------
null        null    null        null    null    null        null
AAA         A       Item_2      B       2       100         No
AAA         A       Item_3      A       3       110         Yes
```

My required result is to compare the `source_product` and `target_product` tables and place the differences in a `final_product` table like this:

**Final_product**:

```
pitem_id    prev_id citem_id    crev_id Validation_error    validation_column   Source_value    target_value
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AAA         A       null        null    pitemid ,prev_id not found in target    null    null    null
AAA         A       Item_2  B   citemid ,crev_id not found in target            
AAA         A       Item_3  A   qty mismatch    qty 1   3
AAA         A       Item_3  A   check_no mismatch   cheeck_no   100 110
AAA         A       Item_3  A   status mismatch status  No  Yes
```

How can I write this query? I tried using union all but am getting duplicates and improper data.

Comment: Post the queries you have tried so far; no one is going to hand you a query. Plus we will know what you have already tried.

Comment: Yes please - may we see the `union all` query you tried, the output it produced, and what was wrong with that output?

Answer (score 0):

`union` is just going to combine multiple result sets (outputs) with the same format into a single aggregate output. You want to combine multiple imputs and process that before generating a single output, so what you want is a `join`. You can follow this sort of template to get the results you want:

```
SELECT
    sourceProduct.*,
    targetProduct.*,
    -- go column by column to determine what matches
    CASE
        WHEN
            (sourceProduct.SomeColumn1 IS NULL AND targetProduct.SomeColumn1 IS NULL)
            OR sourceProduct.SomeColumn1 = targetProduct.SomeColumn1
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS SomeColumn1Matches
    -- keep going as needed
FROM
    SourceProduct sourceProduct
    INNER JOIN TargetProduct targetProduct
        ON sourceProduct.pitem_id = targetProduct.pitem_id -- assumes a full bijection between tables
```

You can adjust the query to format the results and checks and such as needed. If your source and target product tables don't have a bijection between their ids then you'll want to look into a `FULL OUTER JOIN` instead of the `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Could do something like this. You'll have to tweak the syntax/parenthesis I think, but the idea should be obvious.

```
SELECT 'Source' AS disposition,
       srcEtgt.*
  FROM (SELECT * 
          FROM source
        EXCEPT
        SELECT * 
          FROM target
       ) srcEtgt
 UNION
SELECT 'Target' AS disposition,
       tgtEsrc.*
  FROM (SELECT * 
          FROM target
        EXCEPT
        SELECT * 
          FROM source
       ) tgtEsrc
```

Comment: SqlServer does not support `MINUS` but it does support `EXCEPT`.

Comment: @S.C. Huh, thanks for the heads up. Edited. I always though MINUS was standard.